# Joining two entities in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have a category table that have its own unique id and name,
I have a product table that have its own unique id, name, price and categoryId.

Category.java

```
    @Entity
    public class Category {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        
        private String name;
        
        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
        private Set<Product> products;
        //getters and setters
}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    private long productId;
    
    private String name;
    private double price;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
    private Category category;  
    
    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(long productId, String name, double price) {
        super();
        this.productId = productId;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

When I try to create a new product by post method, I should be able to read or write it's categoryId, but I can't. What am I doing it wrong?

Comment: "When I try to create a new product by post method", "should be able to read or write it's categoryId", ...please show!!..."but I can't"...please show/explain ... But my subtle guess already: who sets the id??(what data is already in db?..;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to write its categoryId, but you need a getter and a setter for `Product.category`. To change the category of a product, you would do `product.setCategory(newCategory)`. If you want to READ the category ID of a product, you also need to add a getter for `Category.id`; you would then do: `product.getCategory().getId()`.